# Rails 4: Getting QRCode to display in email via action mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, qr-code

my problem is to get my QRCode to display in the email sent via action mailer in rails.
I am currently using the gem 'rqrcode_png' 
I have read through some guides and it states inline attachment. However, I did not save the QRCode generated in my own files.

Is there a way to display the QRCode in the email without having to save it in my database?
Also, I have tried the following code on my view page and it works, but it does not work when I copy it to my action mailer code. It only shows the **QR Code for venue**.
Here is my code below for the displaying of QRCode. Thank you!

```
<p>
  <% @deal.venues.each do |venue| %>
  <strong>QR Code for <%= venue.neighbourhood %></strong><br>
  <% @qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new(@deal.id.to_s + "_" + venue.id.to_s + "_" + @deal.created_at.to_s).to_img.resize(100, 100).to_data_url %>
  <span><%= image_tag @qr %><br></span>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

**Solution by Lewis Buckley with some edits**

I made some edits to the code and now it is working. As, I am using ruby i have to place <%= %> around the variables in order to display them.

```
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&amp;cht=qr&amp;chl=<%= @deal.id.to_s + '_' + venue.id.to_s + '_' + @deal.created_at.to_s%>" alt="QR code">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure about your exact use case but I have used the Google Chart QR code generator before and it is super simple (you need to url encode your content with the `u` method):

```
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&amp;cht=qr&amp;chl=#{u(@deal.id.to_s + "_" + venue.id.to_s + "_" + @deal.created_at.to_s)}&amp;choe=UTF-8" alt="QR code">
```

And then just copy that into your mailer 'view'.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your suggestion!
Anyways, I had to make some edits to your code to make it work:
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&amp;cht=qr&amp;chl=<%= @deal.id.to_s + '_' + venue.id.to_s + '_' + @deal.created_at.to_s%>" alt="QR code">
Thank you!

Comment: Cool thanks, maybe because I use HAML instead of ERB that is the way I would do it.

Answer (score 1):

Define @url in the controller. Here's examples to `linkto` for debugging and the img source for displaying. The above example used url encoding for & and this didn't work for me. Use & for the urls.

```
<%= link_to("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=545x545&cht=qr&chl=#{@url}&choe=UTF-8","https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=545x545&cht=qr&chl=#{@url}&choe=UTF-8") %>

<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=545x545&;cht=qr&;chl=#{@url}&;choe=UTF-8" alt="QR code">
```

`chs=548x547` is the max allowed size, which you'll need for larger urls.