# Trouble Rendering QR code in Email using Rails ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, qr-code, actionmailer

I am currently able to generate a QR code using ActionMailer but I am unable to actually send that QR code in an email. The element is being sent through properly but the image is broken and it only shows the alt. I can see the QR code in my ActionMailer preview but for some reason it isn't going through when the email is sent/received.

I am using barby to create the QR code in my CompanyLeadRsvpTicketModel.

Here is the code in my model:

```
def generate_qr(text)

  require 'barby'
  require 'barby/barcode'
  require 'barby/barcode/qr_code'
  require 'barby/outputter/png_outputter'

  barcode = Barby::QrCode.new(text, level: :q, size: 5)
  base64_output = Base64.encode64(barcode.to_png({ xdim: 5 }))
  return "data:image/png;base64,#{base64_output}"

end
```

And here is the code in my view:

```
<h1>Hi <%= @company_lead_rsvp_ticket.company_lead[0].first_name%>! Here is your RSVP ticket for the <%=@event.title%>!</h1><h2>Please bring this ticket to check in for the event.</h2><%=image_tag("#{@company_lead_rsvp_ticket.generate_qr(@company_lead_rsvp_ticket.otp_secret_key)}", :alt => "qrcode")%><p><%= @company_lead_rsvp_ticket.confirmation %></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32538786/rails-4-getting-qrcode-to-display-in-email-via-action-mailer) similar to this one and ended up going with the [google-qr gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/google-qr/versions/0.2.2) utilizing the [google charts api](https://github.com/jhsu/google-qr).

It's really easy to use and worked like a charm!

In my model:

```
def generate_qr(text)
require 'google-qr'
chart = GoogleQR.new(:data => "#{text}", :size => "500x500", :margin => 4, :error_correction => "L")
return chart.to_s end
```

In my view:

```
<%=image_tag("#{@company_lead_rsvp_ticket.generate_qr(@company_lead_rsvp_ticket.otp_secret_key)}", :alt => "qrcode")%> <br/>
```

`google-qr` accepts a text input which is uses to generate a qr code and host it using a secure URL. All you have to do is take the data generated by `google-qr` and convert it to a string so it can be used as an image source.

The best part is that if you tried to go directly to this URL in your browser you get a big fat 400 error and you cannot see the QR code.